# Changing the AddThis shared URL in a jQuery mobile application

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, jquery-mobile, addthis

I am experiencing an issue when attempting to dynamically change the URL to be shared with AddThis in my jQuery Mobile application.

The response.url in the code snippet below is a Bitly-provided URL such as "http://shorturl.com/hu7Hnm" however I am unable to change the URL with this code. I do the same thing on our Desktop site and this works fine, however it does not work on our Mobile site (which is jQuery Mobile powered).

The Twitter/Facebook/Email pop-ups still appear, however they show the URL *before* it has been changed by the update code below. So it does not appear to have any affect.

```
// update the AddThis share url to the shortened URL
addthis.update('share', 'url', response.url);
addthis.url = response.url;
addthis.toolbox('.social_icons');
```

The social_icons selector targets this  below which holds the AddThis icons.

```
<ul class="social_icons inline_list">
```

This is an example of my sharing setup on **page load**:

```
var addthis_share = {
      url: "http://www.wrestlemaniamainevent.com/shared/huih897897jkhjkh98907908nn",
      title: "Check out the Main Events at www.wrestlemaniamainevent.com"
}
```

Comment: you want to share url of active page? how do you retrieve the url?

Comment: @Omar Yes, it is the URL of the current page that is being shared. However it is being shortened by Bitly (www.bit.ly). So I want to update the URL to the shortened version, e.g. http://bit.ly/Huk87MN. As I say it works fine on my desktop site, but within the jQM application I can't seem to update the URL correct and have this reflected in the Twitter/Facebook popup that appears - so it appears that AddThis do not recognise the changing of the URL.

Comment: addThis retrieves url using `window.location.href`? Do you have changeHash disabled in JQM?

Comment: @Omar No, `changeHash` is enabled by default and I am not changing this in my code anywhere. I have updated my question to show the `addthis_share` variable that I set on page load. This shows the unshortened URL (before it goes to Bit.ly). This is the URL that I want to update and have AddThis recognise it, but it doesn't appear to be recognised when I use the `addthis.update` call above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to this. It requires specifying the `window` object at the start of the declaration. I believe this is a quirk of using jQM.

`window.addthis.toolbox('.social_icons', {}, {'url': response.url });`